# How to give AWS users access to more than 10+ accounts in an organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We have 10+ accounts clustered under a single root account, all in one organization. Our ops personnel gets a user in the root account and can access any "sub" account in the organization if said user has the required permissions (assumeRole).

I struggle with giving our users the correct permissions (attaching a policy) because IAM is limited everywhere to 10 items:

We have more than 10 sub-accounts. I first tried to attach for each account directly to users, or to groups that give access to users, but I always hit the following limits:

- Groups an IAM user can be a member of: 10
- Managed policies attached to an IAM group: 10
- Managed policies attached to an IAM user: 10 (undocumented)

In order to give users access to an arbitrary number of accounts I need to create up an individual policy for each user it seems. Is that the only way?

Edit: Rephrasing use-case:

I have more than 10 sub-accounts in an organization. I have a bunch of users in an "authorization" AWS account. Users access the sub-accounts via assumeRole as admin. I need a way to give admin access to each user to a subset of accounts. The list of accounts a user can access as admin might change from user to user.

I tried to create a group for each account that has the right policy attached. This allows me to give users admin access by simply adding users with access to the appropriate group. Because I have more than 10 accounts, I need users to be able to belong to more than 10 groups, which isn't possible with AWS.

Comment: You have over ten organisations in the same account, or more than ten accounts under one organisation?

Comment: I clarified the question. We have 10+ accounts. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Without looking this up, you could consider asking AWS to raise the limit, or you could look at federating your login with an on-premise active directory if you have one. There may also be an obvious answer that someone else will come up with, your question isn't quite as clear as I'd like in terms of exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you solve this by using a tree of OUs in your organisation and assigning the relevant polices via the OUs and accounts so they combine permissions as you want them?